# Can't complete HTTP challenge for letsencrypt on Kubernetes

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, lets-encrypt, cert-manager, k3s

I have a k3s cluster and I'm trying to configure it to get a SSL certificate from let's encrypt. I have followed many guides, and I think I'm really near to manage it, but the problem is that the Challenge object in Kubernetes reports this error:

```
Waiting for HTTP-01 challenge propagation: failed to perform self check GET request 'http://devstore.XXXXXXX.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/kVVHaQaaGU7kbYqnt8v7LZGaQvWs54OHEe2WwI_MOgk': Get "http://devstore.XXXXXXX.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/kVVHaQaaGU7kbYqnt8v7LZGaQvWs54OHEe2WwI_MOgk": dial tcp: lookup devstore.XXXXXXX.com on 10.43.0.10:53: no such host
```

It seems that the in some way cert manager is trying to resolve my public DNS name internally, and is not managing to do it, so the challenge is not working. Can you help me on that, I googled it but I cannot find a solution for it...

Thank you

Comment: Could you provide details about your environment, your configuration YAMLs? Which guide you based on? It's local env or cloud env?

Comment: I believe kubernetes comes with its own DNS as part of the `kube-system` namespace which you can scale to 0 instances to turn it off. then this works https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/dns-custom-nameservers/#coredns-configmap-options

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is probable that the DNS record for the domain you want the certificate does not exist.
If if does, and you are using a split horizon DNS config (hijacking the .com domain in your local network) make sure it points out to your public ip (e.g. your home gateway)

[Edit]

Also, you have to figure out LE getting to your cluster in the network, so port-forward 80/443 to your cluster's IPs.

You can get away with it because k3s will default to [cluster traffic policy](https://medium.com/pablo-perez/k8s-externaltrafficpolicy-local-or-cluster-40b259a19404) in the load balancer

Comment: Yes, the cluster is already public available throught the nginx ingress. I don't understand which DNS I should config, I already configured the public DNS (and it's working for the HTTP version of my application), should I configure also the K3S DNS as well? How can I do it? I tought the internal DNS will use the external DNS for a non-authoritative DNS zone.

Comment: so it means your application is maybe hijacking http://devstore.XXXXXXX.com/.well-known/ ?

Comment: No, I don't think so. the application I'm publishing is a very simple HTTP application written in .NET, the only problem is about the SSL certificate. In the various guides I've followed I didn't see any part about the Kubernetes DNS to configure, but the answer I get from cert manager seems to suggest that the problem can be on this...

Comment: There is nothing to configure in the DNS of K8S. you should point your DNS record - public - at cloudflare for example - to your public ip, e.g. app.example.com points to 1.2.3.4 (your public IP).
What happens is cert-manager will make a request to LE server and a bot will visit your public ip on port 80, to go to app.example.com/.well-known/XYZ to verify the token. I've over-simplified the process it's a bit more complex than that.

Comment: It can be that the node you run k3s on has a local DNS you run? if that is so, change it to public DNS (1.1.1.1)

Comment: But it would help a LOT to point you in the right direction if you spend 5 mins describing the environment you run k3s in, what you applied to the cluster etc.

Comment: Ok, I think you're putting me on the right direction. I'm behind a firewall, that is natting me from the public IP to a private one. I think the problem is that the kubernetes node is not able to access the HTTP endpoint because the firewall is not routing correctly the public IP address from the private network. I'm trying different ways to resolve this, but for now no one is working. Can you suggest something? Thank you again!

Comment: If you have a router, port forward 80/443 to the node where cert-manager runs.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/229118/discussion-between-darthhttp-and-sebastiano-gazzola).

Answer (score 0):

This can be caused by multiple different reasons. If you find that it is a transient issue (or possibly if you have misconfigured coredns before), you might want to double-check your coredns configmap (in the `kube-system` namespace).

E.g. you could remove/reduce caching, or point to different DNS nameservers.

[Here's a description](https://www.usepine.com/blog/en/improving-cert-manager-self-check-speed-when-issuing-certificates/) of the issue, where a switch to Google DNS + cache removal helped clear the issue.

Comment: Very good to point it out however the question is about k3s. There is no configuration of CoreDNS required in k3s and most importantly CoreDNS - disregarding of its vendor - forwards to whatever it finds in /etc/resolv.conf on the node where k3s runs.
```forward . /etc/resolv.conf``` @SebastianoGazzola

Comment: @DarthHTTP Thanks for the correction, I didn't notice it's about k3s. 

In other environments the /etc/resolv.conf note can still be useful, though. You might not have a good way to change the node resolvers (e.g. managed DigitalOcean nodes).

Answer (score 0):

Thank you DarthHTTP, I finally manage to make it work! The problem was, as I mentioned on the comment, that the firewall was not routing correctly the HTTP request using the public IP from the private network side. I solved configuring an internal DNS server that is resolving the name with the private IP address of the K3S node, and using that server as the DNS server for the K3S node. Eventually my HTTP web app got a valid let's encrypt certificate!

Comment: Great to hear!
You can get away with using /etc/hosts file instead of setting up a DNS server.